# Image Capture doesn't import photos on iOS 16.0 with macOS Mojave (com.apple.ImageCaptureCore error -9956.)

Tags: iphone, ios, mojave, image-capture

I recently upgraded my iPhone to iOS 16, and now when I cannot import photos and videos from Image Capture.

```
An error occurred while importing. The item “IMG_5591.JPG” was not imported.
```

[image]

When I plugged my iPhone into the Macbook, it prompted me to download and install an update, so I did that.

I have since tried the following online suggestions:

- grant Image Capture Full Disk Access
- grant PTPCamera.app Full Disk Access
- Reboot Macbook
- Reboot Phone
- Different USB cable
- Different USB port

My 2013 Macbook Air is still on Mojave and still runs reasonably snappy - I didn't want to slow it down by installing new OSes.

**Edit**:
Can confirm this is fixed and doesn't happen in iOS 16.1.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a known issue - rumours are that it *may* be fixed in 16.1

MacRumors: [Those on Mojave or older: don't upgrade to iOS 16](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/those-on-mojave-or-older-dont-upgrade-to-ios-16.2358574/)
Apple Community: [ios 16 photo import to Mojave](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254186986)
PiunikaWeb: [iOS 16 users unable to import photos via iTunes ('operation couldn't be completed') on macOS Mojave or older devices](https://piunikaweb.com/2022/10/13/ios-16-users-unable-to-import-photos-via-itunes-on-macos-mojave/)
…and others.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use Airdrop in the meantime.

Comment: Keep us apprised. I'm also on Mojave & haven't jumped to iOS 16 yet. I always wait until things get shaken out, never update before the point one release ;)

Comment: Just upgraded my phone to iOS 16.1 and it doesn't happen anymore - they fixed it.